# How to work with HttpResponse?

Tags: httpresponse

I am able to do a successful callout and get the response just fine.  Having issues referencing the data inside the response.getBody().  What method do you use to be able to reference the data sent back in the body?

Response body is saying:
{"success":true,"data":{"account_number":56789}}

How do I grab the Account Number to reference in the controller?

Comment: It depends on the content of the body really...anything in response.getHeader('Content-Type') to give you a clue? Usually API docs will describe what is coming back from the web service

Comment: Are you looking for https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httpresponse.htm ?

Comment: most of the APIs today return JSON as body so you can use JSON.Deserialize method to convert that information in Apex format

Comment: Updated the question to include more information around the response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, the response you are receiving is a JSON string. You can parse it like this:

```
String json = response.getBody();
Map<String,Object> responseMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(json);
```

Then, you can access it like this:

```
Map<String,Object> dataMap = (Map<String,Object>)responseMap.get('data');
String accountNumber = (String)dataMap.get('account_number');
```